# Nested List not loading in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I am trying to load a Nested list onto my Sencha app. The problem is I am not familiar with it and i am not sure if the json file i am using is correct.

```
[
    {
        "text":[


            {
                "text":"1.1.1",
                "leaf":true

            }],
        "text":[

            {
                "text":"1.1.1",
                "leaf":true

            }
        ]


    }
]
```

This is my store code

```
//Defining the store for the Nested List
Ext.define('InfoImage.store.nestedListStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: 'InfoImage.model.nestedListModel',
    id:'nestedListStore',
    config:{

        //Calling the required model for the Work Item List
        model : 'InfoImage.model.nestedListModel',
        //Defining the proxy for the Work Item List to pull the data for the List
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'app/model/data/list.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'

            }
        },
        autoLoad: true


    }
});
```

and my main code is

```
Ext.define("InfoImage.view.nestedList", {
    extend:'Ext.NestedList',
    xtype:'nestedList',
    id:'nestedList',

    config:{
        fullscreen:'true',
        title:'Nested List',
        xtype:'nestedList',
        //displayField : 'text',
        html:'Nested List on its way!!!',
        store:'nestedListStore'
        //itemTpl:'{text}'
    }
});
```

The output thats displayed is [object object]. I dont know what is missing. ANy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your JSON cannot work with `Ext.NestedList` because `text` is a field of your Model and it should not be declared as rootProperty in your JSON file.

Firstly, assume that you have this model definition:

```
Ext.define('ListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['text']
    }
});
```

According to your data, your JSON file should look like this:

```
items: [
{
    text: '1.1',
    items: [
    { text: '1.1.1', leaf: true },
    { text: '1.1.2', leaf: true }
    ]
    }
]
```

You have to add this config to your Store as well `defaultRootProperty: 'items'`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your Json is a VALID json. Always check for valid json by  pasting the json on [**jsonlint.com**](http://jsonlint.com/)

Secondly, I see that you have commented out the

```
displayField:'text'
```

property. If you don't provide the `displayField` to the `nestedlist`, it won't come to know, which items from the data store to show in the list.

Probably, that's why you are getting the `[object Object]` as your o/p in the list.

Uncomment the above line and check.

Comment: i tried using it but it dint work. So i commented to check if that was the right code. I uncommneted it and tried again. Still doesn work.

Comment: Does it give you the same error? Can you please post the code for your model as well?