# load image using json store

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I am loading a nested list on itemtap. What i need to load is a folder image in case its not a leaf node, and a document image in case its a leaf node.

I think one way of doing that would be loading the image in the json data itself. But am not sure on how to achieve that.

As of now my model consists only of a string data. How would i load an image data in thr?

```
//Defining a data structure for the Nested List
Ext.define('InfoImage.model.nestedListModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

     config:{
    fullscreen:'true',
    title:'Work Items Task 1',
    ui:'normal',
    cls:'nestedlistCls',
    xtype:'nestedList',
    // displayField : 'text',
    store:'nestedListStore'/*,
    getItemTextTpl: function() {
        var tplConstructor = '{text}' +
            '<tpl if="model === \'folder\'">'+
                '<img src="resources/images/refresh.png" >' 
                '</img>' +
            '</tpl>';
        return tplConstructor;
    }*/
   // itemTpl:'<div><img src="resources/images/refresh.png" > </img>{text}</div>'*/


}
});
```

and my json data code is:

```
{
    "items":[

         {
        "text":"1.1",
        "folder":"resources/images/refresh.png",
        "items":[
            {
                "text":"1.1.1",
                "items":[
                    {
                        "text":"1.a",
                        "leaf":true
                    }]
            }
        ]

    },


        {
            "text":"1.2",
            "items":[
                {
                    "text":"1.2.1",
                    "leaf":true
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "text":"1.3",
            "items":[
                {
                    "text":"1.3.1",
                    "leaf":true
                }
            ]

        }
    ]

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: json file is basically just a text file, I think you should fetch the image `src` only and save it as normal string. If so, it's really easy to be done, is that what you need?

Comment: what i need is very simple. I need to have only 2 images. One is loaded in the list when its not a leaf node and other is loaded along with the leaf node. Any idea how i can achieve that?

Comment: it seems that you might want to use these 2 events: `itemtap` and `leafitemtap`

Comment: itemTap and leafItemTap will be called when i already have the list items. I want the list items loaded along with the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, this might be a good reference for you: [Nested List not loading in sencha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332395/nested-list-not-loading-in-sencha/10344594#10344594)

Then the following JSON will suit your need (assume that you've defined `img_src` field in your model as well)

```
items: [
{
    text: 'not_leaf',
    img_src: 'your_link_1',
      items: [
        { text: 'leaf_1', img_src: 'your_link_2',  leaf: true },
        { text: 'leaf_2', img_src: 'your_link_3', leaf: true }
      ]
    }
]
```

Then Sencha Touch automatically loads all of your **image sources**  and you can do whatever you want with them.

**Note**: If what you want to do is just listen & handle events, use `itemtap` and `leafitemtap` event on your `Ext.NestedList`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that. I am pasting the code i tried here. Its not working yet.

Comment: I am getting the path of the image in the list and nothing else.

Comment: it seems what you want to do is download the real image data through JSON? It's impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: if you just want to display your list items with your images, it's possible, but if you want to download & store real image data, it's not

Comment: I just want to display the list items with images provided i use a diff one for non-leaf data and leaf data.

Comment: ok, use this: `getItemTextTpl: function(){whatever you want here, finally return a string }`, an example is described here: http://sencha-nested-list.heroku.com/app/views/Viewport.js. I think you can find solution yourself through this. If not, please tell me and I'll explain in more details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10681/discussion-between-khush-and-thiem-nguyen)